# customize product loop template for woocommerce generated by Gutenberg Editor

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, wordpress-gutenberg, storefront

I would like to display some custom post-meta into the product loop in woocommerce.

My function works in the loops for display in default Shop page.

However it is not working when product loop is generated by shortcode through the edit page/ Gutenberg Editor.

The code in question is(when viewing code in Gutenberg Editor):

```
wp:woocommerce/product-new {"align":"full"}
```

The above code will return a product loop but I would like to add something to it to display post-meta of each product inside the loop. However I do not know a way to access the template of it.

For example, the following `remove_action` does work with the default loop in the Shop page, but it wont affect the loops generated by Gutenberg Editor.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'free_tag', 0);
function free_tag(){
    global $product;
    if( $product->get_price() == 0){
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart'); 
    }else{
        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart');}
};
                      }
```

The loop in Shop page is using `content-product.php` in `....plugins\woocommerce\templates`, but editing `content-product.php` doesnt affect loops generated by Gutenberg Editor.

Where can I find the hooks and template for loops generated by woocommerce in Gutenberg Editor?